# JQuery Mobile slider with label vertical align

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have the following annoying issue, you can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wigiri/XMKGW/). Its a simple slider with a label, here's the HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="general-settings-list">
    <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-btn ui-li ui-btn-inner">
    <div>
    <label class="ui-label" for="shake">Shake</label>
    </div>
    <div id="slider-container">
    <select name="shake" id="shake" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

With the following CSS (using Jquery Mobile 1.3, css and js):

```
#slider-container {
    position: relative;
    float:right;  
    margin-top: -10px !important;    
}

#slider-container .ui-slider {
    margin-top: -50px !important;
}
```

When I resize the display (ie. window size) instead of being aligned as it should be:
[image: The goal]

It shows unaligned like this:

[image: The problem]

Any ideas?

Comment: JQM adds `margin-bottom: .4em` when the window shrinks. `.ui-field-contain label.ui-slider { margin-bottom: .4em; }`. Override this by using `@media` and set it to `0` instead of `.4em`.

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP Thanks! I am no expert on CSS, can you show the code for `@media`?

Comment: Just a small hint/advice, test your code on a normal browser or phone device. your code looks totally different on chrome, not like the one on JSfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the CSS to:

```
#slider-container {
    position: relative;
    float:right;  
    margin-top: -8px !important;    
}
```

It works now